# How to upload video to mysql database in php?

Tags: php, mysql

How to upload video to mysql database in php (that is, to the server and already upload it to the page, but I only need to add the video)? I have 2 forms for selecting this file and I need to click on 1 button, and 2 photos and videos load, here are my download forms:

```
<form action="load_video.php" method="post">
    <p>Обложка видео</p>
    <input type='file' name='uploadfile_img_video'><br>
    <p>Видео</p>
    <input type='file' name='uploadfile_video'><br>
    <p>Название видео</p>
    <input name="name_video" type="text"><br>
    <p>Описание видео</p>
    <textarea name="description_video" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button name="add_video_btn">Добавить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want to upload the video to your MySQL database?

Comment: I want to upload files to the server, and then add to the database

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago, I asked this kinda question, and I was advised not to store images or videos in the database, as it would limit performance and functionality. Its best to upload the video to a storage, and store the link to access the video in the database as a `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` field.

If you must store images or videos in the database, they can be stored as blobs. But as I've advised earlier, don't do this!

```
<form action="load_video.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p>Обложка видео</p>
   <input type='file' name='uploadfile_img_video'><br>
   <p>Видео</p>
   <input type='file' name='uploadfile_video'><br>
   <p>Название видео</p>
   <input name="name_video" type="text"><br>
   <p>Описание видео</p>
   <textarea name="description_video" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
   <br>
   <button type="submit" name="add_video_btn">Добавить</button>
<form>
```

Notice that I added:

1. `enctype="multipart/form-data"`as one of the form attributes. This is required for all file uploads
2. `type="submit"` as an attribute to the button element. That's what makes it possible for you to submit your form :).

Check [How to Upload a file in PHP](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-a-file-in-php-with-example--cms-31763), and other online tutorials that'll help you with the subject ;)